# Stuck on deploying WAR file. "FAIL - Application at context path / could not be started"

Tags: apache, maven, tomcat, jar, war

After going through Maven commands on my project, importing the WAR file onto the webapps folder on Tomcat, I'm greeted with a FAIL - Application at context path / could not be started. My WAR file is a ROOT.WAR. Is this a problem with Tomcat's XML configuration? Here's my log of errors, I have no clue which is the crucial error to address.

Here's the console log from Eclipse trying to start the Tomcat server.
http://pastebin.com/JMZqWKhF

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually look at the logfile you posted? The first stacktrace in the incomplete logfile contains:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%208.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
    ...
at com.pethers.afriqcart.service.geoip.CityDatabaseLookupService.loadExternalDatabase(CityDatabaseLookupService.java:59)
    at com.pethers.afriqcart.service.geoip.CityDatabaseLookupService.<init>(CityDatabaseLookupService.java:40)
```

I've omitted a few irrelevant lines, maybe this helps identifying *this* cause?

As there seems to be a lot more missing from the top of the log it might only be a secondary problem - but that'd be your own problem then... Read your logs

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to this. This is my first time trying to deploy WAR files through Tomcat.

Comment: I'm not sure which one is main cause for the WAR to not be deployed.

Comment: The "main" cause is probably the first error you'll find in your log. Unfortunately your log starts somewhere in the middle. Check if tomcat/logs/catalina.out is there or where else the server actually logs. Raise the buffer size for the console if you're using `startup.bat`